# Cache facade not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want some settings to be user-manageable. Because of this, I am storing them in database, retrieving and caching them afterwards. However, when I try to call `Cache` facade inside the `config/config.php` file, I get an error. Details are given below.

I have following code located in `app/config/custom.php`:

```
<?php 
// app/config/custom.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

return [
   'foo' => Cache::get('foo');
];
```

Which spits out a following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   D:\www\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
>   on line 216

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have enabled the Cache ?

Comment: @ToyRobotic Yes, I have cache driver set to 'file'. I suspect this issue is caused because I'm trying to use Cache inside config file, although I have no idea why is that even a problem

Comment: Facades were in global namespace if I'm not mistaken inside helpers.php can you change the use statement to use Cache;

Comment: make it like this: \Cache::put('foo', 'bar'); and see if it will work

Comment: would you share your `custom.php` code?

Comment: Try to `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;` (starting backslash).

Comment: @MinaAbadir Sure, I've simplified the code, but essentially, it's the same. Please look at the updated question.

Comment: @engvrdr it says, that class 'Cache' was not found

Comment: @ClearBoth it says, that class 'Cache' was not found

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu nothing changed

Comment: Just use `use Cache;`
Did you store anything?

Comment: where is the namespace of your file app/Http/Helpers/helpers.php?

Comment: @bobbybackblech Yes, I'm sure. The error is caused because the system can'f find the Cache object and calls `get()` on null. `use Cache;` doesn't work either

Comment: @ClearBoth it doesn't have one. Is it required?

Comment: no, just wondering. If it says call to a member function then facades already linked so no wrong in namspcaces. why not try Illuminate\Cache\Repository instead of using facades.

Comment: @ClearBoth I don't think so, because the error says that `get()` is called on **non-object**. How should I use that repository?

Comment: You cannot technically do that, if I understand Laravel correctly. The Facades are loaded in the container after evaluating the config files.

Comment: @MinaAbadir Thanks! That confirms my thoughts. Is there some sort of workaround to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I have added my response in an answer to have global benefit to the community. We can continue our discussion, please provide details for what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, config files are not meant to store dynamic application values, if it's dynamic (i.e. User specific values), you should handle them in different parts of the application.

You can make something available globally throughout your application by using Service Providers.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I think, it answers why the code above isn't working. I've asked a different question taking into account impossibility to use Facades in the config files. Please see more detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673236/is-it-a-good-idea-to-edit-env-dynamically-in-laravel-5

Comment: As discussed, my answer here is not meant to get more reputation, it's for the community benefit. That being said, it answers your question and why you are getting the error and some recommendation on how make some value available to the different application parts. The best way to store admin panel settings is through DB, and you load those values from a Mailer model in the case you have mentioned for setting mail server settings.

Comment: I would rather avoid loading settings somewhere other than config files, because it will introduce unnecessary confusion in the codebase

Comment: User specific settings are not meant to be loaded in the configuration files. Configuration files are for system wide settings. Loading user specific settings in configuration files will create the confusion you are worrying about, as it's against the standard system architecture.

Comment: I am required to implement user-changeable settings. Now, imagine, that another developer inherits the codebase. He goes to smtp settings and changes them only to find, that the changes he made have no effect! Imagine his rage and frustration, after many liters of sweat and tears, he eventually finds, that the mailer takes settings from some non-conventional place instead of the conventional one.

Comment: Indeed, we have to use [service providers](https://medium.com/@razamoh/create-own-custom-helper-functions-classes-in-laravel-e8d2f50ff38). In that case, I wanted to implement custom helpers and it didn't work to call the helpers function from the config files, but as a service provider