# Is it a good idea to edit .env dynamically in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade, phpdotenv

I am building an admin panel, so I need to make some **core settings** (like smtp settings, etc) of my Laravel 5 app configurable to end users through front-end interface.

My initial thoughts were to use database as a settings storage alongside caching(to avoid issuing database calls every time a config value is accessed). However, it appears, that [Facades are loaded after config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667310/cache-facade-not-working-in-laravel-5), thus the code below doesn't work:

```php
<?php
// app/config/custom_settings.php

return [
    'key' => Cache::get('key');
];
```

Because of this, I am thinking about **writing the user's configuration directly into .env** file programmatically. Is this a good idea, or can it turn into a headache in the future?

Comment: You should store them as flat files in `storage/app`. You can read them into the Config, overwriting values, or write a config handler. The handler could give you some advantages like validating settings.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store it in your database, in the user's table or in another related table?

I think the .env file is for global settings (database, mail config, cache config,...) but it has not thought to store end user configs.

Comment: I'll update the question to address these issues. However, I need to give user a possibility to tinker with the app-specific configs like smtp and other ones, as I'm building an admin panel.